# preg_replace and array for multiple domains

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have an array like this:

```
$array =  array('domain1.com','domain2.net','domain3.org');
```

any way to replace only these domains into links with preg_replace?

currently have this little function, but parses all the domains:

```
                function insert_referer($text){
                    $text = preg_replace('#(script|about|applet|activex|chrome):#is', "\\1:", $text);
                    $ret = ' ' . $text;
                    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])([\w]+?://[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
                    $ret = preg_replace("#(^|[\n ])((www|ftp)\.[\w\#$%&~/.\-;:=,?@\[\]+]*)#is", "\\1<a href=\"http://\\2\" target=\"_blank\">\\2</a>", $ret);
                    $ret = substr($ret, 1);
                    return $ret;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you wanted:

```
$array = array('domain1.com','domain2.net','domain3.org');
$text = 'Some text including domain1.com/something and http://domain3.org';
echo preg_replace('/((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:' . implode('|', $array) . ')[-a-zA-Z0-9\._~:\/?#\[\]@\!\$&\'\(\)\*\+,;=]*)/', '\1', $text);
// Outputs:
// "Some text including <a href="domain1.com/something">domain1.com/something</a> and <a href="http://domain3.org">http://domain3.org</a>"
```

I didn't test the code itself so it may (I don't think it would but it's possible) contain typos, but I tested the regexp itself and it works perfectly.